PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when retrieving tif images in local file
I am trying to get a module to import tif documents form files on my computer with python
and this is the error message I am getting:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'C:\Users\abouf\OneDrive\Desktop\Deep_Learning\Training_Data\T\images'

Hey all,
This is the part if code I am running in python:
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from patchify import patchify, unpatchify
import tifffile as tif
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.optimizers import Adam

# import labels and images
large_image_stack = tif.imread(r"C:\Users\abouf\OneDrive\Desktop\Deep_Learning\Training_Data\T\images")
large_mask_stack = tif.imread(r"C:\Users\abouf\OneDrive\Desktop\Deep_Learning\Training_Data\T\labels")

all_img_patches = []

and this is the error message I am getting:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'C:\Users\abouf\OneDrive\Desktop\Deep_Learning\Training_Data\T\images'

Anyone can help with this?

It seems like tif.imread expects a filename not a directory. I wasn't able to find the docs for tifffile but you could check out the source to see which parameters are allowed

Option 1: Try running your Python IDE (like Anaconda, PyCharm, etc.) or script as an administrator in the command prompt.
Option 2: As a test, try copying the TIF files to a different directory such as C:\Temp and see if you can access the files from there.
Option 3: Make sure no other applications are using the files you are trying to access. Close any applications that may be using these files.
Option 4: Use os.listdir to Check the Directory, you can list the files in the directory to make sure Python can access it:
import os

directory_path = r"C:\Users\abouf\OneDrive\Desktop\Deep_Learning\Training_Data\T\images"
print(os.listdir(directory_path))

Thanks.
